Is there a way to use a Message type as a type in another Message?
I'd like to assign a "message" type to Message so payload can be either Sms or Email. This is not valid type as the error says message not defined in reference to the "message" type I'm assigning to payload.
Is there some way I can make the payload be a generic enough type that it can be either Sms or Email?
syntax = "proto3";


message Sms {
    ...
}

message Email {
    ...
}


message Message {
    // Can be any form of communication.
    message payload = 1;  // I want to make this any kind of message. 
}

Alternatively, I was going to add both types able to be assignable to the Message.
syntax = "proto3";


message Sms {
    ...
}

message Email {
    ...
}


message Message {
    // Can be any form of communication.
    optional Sms sms = 1;
    optional Email email = 2;
}


using oneOf for multiple message types or you can use Any for more Flexibility

message Message {
  oneof payload {
    Sms sms = 1;
    Email email = 2;
  }
}


In this case you'd still have 2 separate parameters right? It's just that they're now mutually exclusive. So there seems no way to have a single parameter?

@engineer-x the closest .proto comes to that is: oneof; some implementations may take this further - for example, protobuf-net allows oneof and polymorphism to overlap, so: if Sms : MessageBase and Email : MessageBase, then you could send a MessageBase and it would be data-comptible with oneof
